# Bootstrap columns inside Kendo Tabstrip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tabstrip

I have a Kendo Tabstrip and I'm trying to format its content using Bootstrap. But Tabstrip's border, `k-content k-state-active`, is rendered at top and my elements are outside. If I don't use Bootstrap, everything will be fine. I have already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979648/) and it doesn't solve my problem.

This is my code:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
    .Name("tabstrip")
    .Items(items =>
    {
   //removed 
        items.Add()
            .Text("اطلاعات حساب‌ها")
            .Content(@<text>

    <div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LiCode1, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LiCode1, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LiCode2, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LiCode2, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm" })
        </div>
    </div>
            </text>);
    })
    )
</div>
```

It seems I can't use `col-*` class at all, so how should I format the elements?

By border I mean the green line in below picture, if I remove the `col-*` it will contain elements.

[image: Ruined formatting in Kendo Tabstrip]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add container if you are using Bootstrap grid system

from their documentation

> **Containers**
>
> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and house our grid system. You may choose one of two
>   containers to use in your projects.

There are class `.container` and `.container-fluid`, therefore you need to wrap your TabStrip's content using one of these class.

```
items.Add()
            .Text("اطلاعات حساب‌ها")
            .Content(@<text>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LiCode1, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LiCode1, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.LiCode2, new { @class = "control-label col-xs-3" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LiCode2, new { @class = "form-control  input-sm" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't help. (as feedback)