# My bootstrap columns inside Kendo window with tabstrips are collapsing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, kendo-window, kendo-tabstrip

I have a very specific problem. I have a kendo window that has a left tabstrip navigation and inside each tab there is a form wizard. The form is using bootstrap to columnize each form input.

I am using 'col-xs-6' which should put two forms inline with each other but they are not. I have tried to place a container-fluid div from this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419623/bootstrap-columns-inside-kendo-tabstrip) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979648/tabstrip-containing-bootstrap-columns?lq=1) (hack, but didn't work) have also tried to resize the width of the window but the two forms still collapse on each other.

The only solution to this is if I change the cols to 'col-xs-5' but if 'xs' is to never collapse, and col-xs-6 is supposed to take 50% of the divs width, then why is it stacking? I appreciate the help!

Desired solution image:

[image: here]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form id="general-info" method="POST" action="#">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>General Information</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="company-name">Company Name *</label>
                        <input class="form-control required" id="company-name" name="#" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="client-id">ClientId *</label>
                        <input class="form-control required" id="client-id" name="#" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="account-manager">Account Manager</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="account-manager" name="#" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <label for="manager-email">Account Manager Email</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="manager-email" name="#" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Client Information</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <img id="image" src="#" height="100" width="200" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <p>Select a logo to upload</p>
                        <p class="text-muted">Valid File Types: jpg, jpeg, png, bmp, gif</p>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file required" id="photos" onchange="readURL(this);" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 client-domain">
                        <label for="domain-prefix">Domain Prefix *</label>
                        <input class="form-control required" id="domain-prefix" name="#" type="text" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <hr>
        <fieldset>
            <div class='modal-buttons'>
                <div style='float: left;'>
                    <button class="save-button">Save</button>
                    <button class="close-button">Close</button>
                </div>
                <div style='float: right;'>
                    <button class="next-button">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem in Kendo's documentation, [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/using-kendo-with-twitter-bootstrap#nest-widgets-and-bootstrap-grid-layout). I know there may be some people who will run into this problem in the future. I hope this answer finds them well.

Basically, Kendo UI uses the default content-box box model while boostrap uses the non-default border-box model and applies it to all elements on the page, including unrelated ones, in which this case, Kendo Windows. To override Bootstrap's CSS, you can apply content-box box model to all elements like so:

```
*, :before, :after
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

and then use border-box model only to Bootstrap elements which needs it:

```
.form-control,
.container,
.container-fluid,
.row,
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1,
.col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2,
.col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3,
.col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4,
.col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5,
.col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6,
.col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7,
.col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8,
.col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9,
.col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10,
.col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11,
.col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!