# Kendo Modal window & bootstrap column issues

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, modal-dialog

I am using Kendo Modal window and bootstarp. I have kendo window and have to split the two divs with column. For responsive design I have to use bootstrap classes like row and col-md-12.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <button onclick='myFunction()'>Open Window</button>
  <div id="win1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"  style="border:1px solid Red;">
        First
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="border:1px solid Blue;">
        Second
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
 <script>
    function myFunction() {

      $("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
        width: "300px",
        height: "200px",
        modal: true,
        title: "Window 1",
       });
    }
  </script>
```

I know that, Bootstarp class row divides in 12 parts.
So, First and Second  div should appear in the first row. Why it is displayed in two rows. This is my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/068jqOHlV0WFOBRo8qCs?p=preview)

Comment: It is a CSS box-sizing issue. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140070/bootstrap-3-grid-system-does-not-work-correctly-within-a-3rd-party-styled-div-k/3

Comment: As mentioned in the link, I have included "kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" & "kendo.bootstrap.min.css". Still issue persist. Any other I need to do to fix this issue?

Comment: You missed the box-sizing issue. You need to set it to border-box for any bootstrap elements that are within kendoui widgets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979648/tabstrip-containing-bootstrap-columns

Answer (score 0):

When you open the inspector you can see that there is a error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

This means Bootstrap is not loading properly and the css used the create the columns is not working. You can see that it is missing these styles:

```
 widht:50%; float:left;
```

If you apply them manually you can see that it works.

Comment: Not getting any error. Why need to provide width 50% it should handled by bootstarp

Comment: Yes I know. But it isn't handled by bootstrap so that means there is something wrong whith the file inclusion.

Comment: Bootstarp css is not properly included thats why it is showing error? Bootstrap href- https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css which correctly opens up the css

Comment: Well as far as i know that would be the issue. If you open the inspecter and go over to the col-md-6 you can see that it doesn't have widht:50%; and float:left; .

Comment: One more thing why scroll bar at bottom. Controls should be placed correctly in the available space

Comment: try downloading the file and uploading it to your server to include it that way. It looks like your server is not allowing external resources.

Comment: That is from the margins on the .row class. You could remove those or put overflow overflow-x: hidden;  on the body tag.

Comment: @user2323308 Did you fix the problem?

Comment: @user2323308 Well, nice that you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the elements in you flunk you can see there is no width assigned to them. You did use the correct classes / structure but it failed loading, as said by Arjan Knol.

Try to load bootstrap in another way so that it will load and you should the wished results.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen as well. It is a box sizing issue as ezanker points out. So I added this class to my global css:

```
.border-box, .border-box * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    [class^="k-"] {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
}
```

and then if I'm putting content inside a kendo window, template, etc. I wrap it with that class:

```
<div class="border-box">
    ...form groups, controls, etc.
</div>
```